# Is there a resource leak here?

Tags: go, concurrency, channel, goroutine

```
func First(query string, replicas ...Search) Result {
  c := make(chan Result)
  searchReplica := func(i int) {
    c <- replicas[i](query)
  }
  for i := range replicas {
    go searchReplica(i)
  }
  return <-c
}
```

This function is from the slides of Rob Pike on go concurrency patterns in 2012. I think there is a resource leak in this function. As the function return after the first send & receive pair happens on channel c, the other go routines try to send on channel c. So there is a resource leak here. Anyone knows golang well can confirm this? And how can I detect this leak using what kind of golang tooling?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, you are right (for reference, here's the [link to the slide](https://talks.golang.org/2012/concurrency.slide#48)). In the above code only one launched goroutine will terminate, the rest will hang on attempting to send on channel `c`.

Detailing:

- `c` is an unbuffered channel
- there is only a single receive operation, in the `return` statement
- A new goroutine is launched for each element of `replicas`
- each launched goroutine sends a value on channel `c`
- since there is only 1 receive from it, one goroutine will be able to send a value on it, the rest will block forever

Note that depending on the number of elements of `replicas` (which is `len(replicas)`):

- if it's `0`: `First()` would block forever (no one sends anything on `c`)
- if it's `1`: would work as expected
- if it's `> 1`: then it leaks resources

The following modified version will not leak goroutines, by using a non-blocking send (with the help of `select` with `default` branch):

```
searchReplica := func(i int) {
    select {
    case c <- replicas[i](query):
    default:
    }
}
```

The first goroutine ready with the result will send it on channel `c` which will be received by the goroutine running `First()`, in the `return` statement. All other goroutines when they have the result will attempt to send on the channel, and "seeing" that it's not ready (send would block because nobody is ready to receive from it), the `default` branch will be chosen, and thus the goroutine will end normally.

Another way to fix it would be to use a buffered channel:

```
c := make(chan Result, len(replicas))
```

And this way the send operations would not block. And of course only one (the first sent) value will be received from the channel and returned.

Note that the solution with any of the above fixes would still block if `len(replicas)` is `0`. To avoid that, `First()` should check this explicitly, e.g.:

```
func First(query string, replicas ...Search) Result {
    if len(replicas) == 0 {
        return Result{}
    }
    // ...rest of the code...
}
```

Some tools / resources to detect leaks:

- https://github.com/fortytw2/leaktest
- https://github.com/zimmski/go-leak
- https://medium.com/golangspec/goroutine-leak-400063aef468
- https://blog.minio.io/debugging-go-routine-leaks-a1220142d32c

Comment: Thanks for your reasoning. It is quite clear. Would you please be kind again to give some hint or suggestion on what's the right golang tooling to address this kind of issue, say, resources leaks

Comment: @David That part of the question is off-topic for Stack Overflow, but see edited answer.